# Saving a null date to SQL2008 via. SubSonic 2.x

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, nullable, subsonic2.2

Ok, So I am trying to set a datetime column to null via SubSonic 2.x

```
DateTime? dt = new DateTime();
dt= null;
Datum pd = (new DatumCollection()
                    .Where(Datum.Columns.Data, cp[0].Data)
                    .Load())[0];

                pd.dtAcceptance = (DateTime)dt;
                pd.Save();
```

Even though the database column allows for a null value, it won't save and I've tried a couple of other options, including setting it to DateTime.MinValue (1/1/0001 is too early a date I guess).  I get 'Nullable object must have a value'

I've been searching here and Google for some magic bullet to fix what I think is a pretty stupid problem to have.  Is there something in the SubSonic generation I need to change to allow it to work or do I have to write some stupid trigger on the SQL side that if a date comes in with '1/1/1900' to change it to NULL ?

help and thanks!

stack:
"Nullable object must have a value."
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at Services.Decision.OnDecline(Int32 nParticipantID, Int32 nSessionID) in C:\dev\app\server\Services\Decision.cs:line 426

Comment: Are you sure that the "Nullable object must have a value" is on the line you think it is?  Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh.  You are casting dt to a DateTime, but you need to cast it to a nullable DateTime `(DateTime?)`

Comment: pd.dtAcceptance is a DateTime not a DateTime?
SubSonic generated it as such which was why I was wondering if I needed to change something in the SubSonic template to allow for nullable dates

Comment: Sorry - yes - the template should be a nullable DateTime if the field allows for nulls.

Comment: heh, any idea where to change that?  simple task getting worse and worse, but thanks for the directional change

Comment: Sorry - I don't know SubSonic well - I just saw it was an ORM so figured it worked like other generation tools.  Don't you point it at the database and it creates the layer for you?  Is the column in your database nullable?

Comment: oh yeah, it is.  I hate SubSonic, it is to the point where I might just create a stored procedure for this and hook it in place because I've already spent way too much time on this.  thanks for the help

Comment: What about the ORM stuff inside of Visual Studio?  That can create the same layer for you.

Comment: OK, figured it out.
pd.AdviceAcceptanceHasValue = false;
SubSonic creates the boolean that if you set to false it sets the NULL to the db behind the scenes.  Marking your answer as accepted since I took your time.